# Why I can't build opencv WITH_QT?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, qt5

I've installed Qt5.12 on my Windows 7 x64. And CMake 3.16.

I want to build OpenCV-4.1.2. So in cmake I've checked `WITH_QT` and specified `QT5_DIR` as: `C:\\Qt\\5.12.6` and then I click Configure. But I get this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:669 (include)"
```

Comment: Does C:\Qt\5.12.6 contain either Qt5Config.cmake or qt5-config.cmake?

Comment: Are you sure that the directory C:\\Qt\\5.12.6 contains either of these files (Qt5Config.cmake or qt5-config.cmake)?

Comment: The variables are *case-sensitive*, so you should set `Qt5_DIR` as it suggests, not `QT5_DIR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured it out: I've made a search inside the Qt directory for `Qt5Config.cmake` and found it in: "C:\Qt\5.12.6\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5".

- Now I specify this directory in CMake and click configure. Everything works fine. Thank you guys.